# How to get location of a pdf file opened in preview

Tags: pdf, preview

I have opened a pdf file in preview, without knowing where this file is located. How can I find out?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Simply <kbd>⌘</kbd>+Click on it's name in the title bar or secondary click (right click) on it .

(I have a polish OS X on the screenshot)

[image]

Comment: wow... that was "easy" to find.... thanks for the help as I couldn't find it for the life of me!

Comment: @BradParks you can also secondary/right click on it too.

Comment: Bit late, but worth pointing out that this works in all applications that have standard windows*. I use this feature every day and find it so annoying when I have to use Windows. You can also drag the icon itself if you hold the mouse button down for a short time before you drag, e.g. to drag the file to the Trash.
* Except for some non-standard apps, and if you're looking at an MS Office document opened from SharePoint I don't think it works either.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't allow saving the path to the clipboard; I've asked that question specifically here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327085/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file-opened-in-preview-saved-into-the-clipboard

Comment: But I happen to find that if the path is too long, it will fail. Say that the path is `/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/as/fsd/awe/wqeq/123/w/re/qw`

Comment: In macOS Big Sur, title bar click behavior has changed: open file location in Finder => move file location with one click. So anyone knows how to "open file location in Finder" in Big Sur?

Answer (score 20):

1. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>  this opens a dialogue with the current file.
2. Select the file, and press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, this reveals the file in Finder.
3. In Finder, select the file, and press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, this copies the full path to the Clipboard.

Comment: How on Earth did you figure these hotkeys out? I'm trying to understand where these shortcuts are defined.

Comment: Not that easy. But not that hard being a geek :)

Comment: Any pointer? It would help guide my search.

Comment: Here: http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/06/10-essential-keyboard-shortcuts-for-the-open-save-dialog-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: those 3 steps work well.

I'm sure there used to be a reveal in Finder option in the menu that would open the containing folder in the finder. Super simple.

This is now silly and causes a long time to do a simple action.
super frustrating

Answer (score 2):

Mojave - just click on the name, it will reveal the popup window with location. Alternatively, you can hover the cursor over the name - it will invoke a little downward arrow - click on it and you'll see the same popup with location.