# Copy full path of an open file

Tags: macos, file, path

I have a file open in Preview.app. I can easily [view the full path](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144232/how-to-get-location-of-a-pdf-file-opened-in-preview) for the same by  <kbd>⌘</kbd>  + clicking on the file proxy icon (the icon shown besides the filename in Preview's title bar).

How do I copy the full path to clipboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>  this opens a dialogue with the current file.
2. Select the file, and press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, this reveals the file in Finder.
3. In Finder, select the file, and press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, this copies the full path to the Clipboard.

Comment: Similar to the accepted answer, but a bit more direct to accomplish the goal. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can copy the full file path.

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + click on the file proxy icon (shown in Preview's title bar). This will reveal the full disk path of the file, shown as hierarchy of directories starting from the root (topmost) directory in the filesystem.
2. Click on the name of the parent directory (the directory containing the file) of the file. This will open the directory in Finder.app with the file automatically selected.

[image]

3. Now secondary click (or <kbd>Control</kbd> + click) on the selected file icon, then press and hold <kbd>Option</kbd> key. This will give you an option in the context menu to copy the pathname of the file.

[image]

Performing this action will copy the full pathname of the file in the clipboard. The copied pathname in this example is as shown below:

`/Users/nimeshneema/Desktop/WWDC 2018.png`

Using this technique, full pathname of any file can be copied from the Finder.

Comment: thanks, just accepted answer; but a bit sad there's not a more direct way for such a basic feature...

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but maybe this can be automized with a shortcut?